# Update version number in vdproj / Setup File via Cruise Control

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, vdproj

we have got an automated Build Solution using Cruise Control (& msbuild files), which allows us to automatically updated the file versions with the build number for "normal" executables.

But what about setup projects or more specifically the vdproj files. Is there any way to automatically update the version of vdproj files and thus the resulting msi installer files of the setup projects?

(Just to clarifiy: The exes that are installed with the msi installers show the correct version numbers, but what I am now wondering about specifically is the versioning of the msi installers that are created by the setup projects via vdproj files.)

If it matters we have VS2010 installed on our build server.

Thanks all for your help!